# How does Tomcat sets cipher suite to entire JVM and not just specific connector?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I've noticed that when I configure in server.xml of Tomcat a specific cipher suite for a SSL connector it influences the entire JVM. Meaning, that when I create a `socket` from the `SSLSocketFactory` it contains only this specific cipher.
**Can anybody please explain me how it is done? How Tomcat enables the configured cipher to affect any new socket?**
I'm using **Tomcat 8** and **JDK 1.8.0_91**.
Here is the server.xml section:

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" address="$ip" port="443" 
enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https"
secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" 
keystoreFile="..." keystorePass="XXX" truststoreFile="..." truststorePass="XXX" 
sslProtocol="TLS" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2" ciphers="$cipher_suites" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set it somewhere global yourself, e.g. `javax.net.ssl.cipherSuites` or whatever it is?

Comment: I'm sure, I only updated the server.xml. I also used several cipher suites and each time my configuration affected the entire JVM. BTW is there a way to set the `cipherSuites` property in a configuration file? (I tried to set it in `java.security` on the client side and it didn't work)